# Extending ClaimsPrincipal class with IsAuthenticated property

Tags: c#, extension-methods, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to extend ClaimsPrincipal class with properties. I want to add property IsAuthenticated which would basically return IsAuthenticated from already existing Identity property. So far I have it done as a function:

```
    public static bool IsAuthenticated(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        return principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```

I would like to convert this to property instead.

Comment: Although .net is not supporting extension of properties, for some insight: [Easy extension of properties in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386911/Csharp-Easy-Extension-Properties)

Answer (score 1):

C# or VB.NET don't support *extension properties*.